# id selector is not working but class selector is working. Using Variable in the selector

Tags: jquery

This is not working when I try to use id selector:

```
$("<div>",{id:"o"+i,"class":"overlay"}).appendTo("#"+i);
$("<div>",{id:"te"+i,"class":"text"}).appendTo(".overlay");
$("#te"+i).html(id);
```

But this is working when I use class selector:

```
$("<div>",{"class":"overlay"}).appendTo("#"+i);
$("<div>",{"class":"text"}).appendTo(".overlay");
$(".text").html(id);
```

My Frame looks like this:

```
<div class = "GalleryandRate" id = "GalleryandRate">
  <div id="gallery" onload="mygallery()">
    <div class="movie">
      <img src="SX300.jpg" alt="poster" width="250" height="350">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">a variable</div>
      </div>
      <div class="title">scooby doo</div>
      <button class="nominate" ><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Nominate </button>
    </div>
  </div>
<div id="rate">
</div>
```

Thank you

UPDATE:

Since people asking why not set text when create element. There is a loop, for each movie in json data, each where have one specific description on overlay effect on the poster.The text element's innerhtml will be that description for that one movie.

Detailed code can be seen at https://github.com/UneSaltedFish/Nominate_Movie it is also hosting on https://unesaltedfish.github.io/Nominate_Movie/ for view what I mean by overlay effect when put cursor on the picture.

Comment: `.appendTo(".overlay")` will append the element to *all* elements with `class="overlay"`. Maybe you meant `.appendTo("#o"+i)`?

Comment: It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/7zap3r2b/1/

Comment: How Am I not notice that!!!!! I stuck Here for two day! Thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: This solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

As Barmar said, I didn't notice and need to change .overlay to #"o"+i

```
$("<div>",{id:"o"+i,"class":"overlay"}).appendTo("#"+i);
$("<div>",{id:"te"+i,"class":"text"}).appendTo("#o"+i);
$("#te"+i).html(id);
```

This works perfect!